# How do I determine when a browser completely disconnects from my site using socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Because people can open many tabs and use many browsers, I have some troubles of determining when user close all tabs of each browser.

Comment: Each tab has it's own socket connection. Just check for `on("disconnect"` event

Comment: @SterlingArcher That's disconnection of the tab. How do you know if all tabs are closed (All tabs are closed is the same as browser is closed)

Comment: Do you have a user login that identifies a given user, no matter what browser they use?

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry. I don't want to detect user disconnection, I need to detect the disconnection of browser.

Comment: Why do you mention a user using many different browsers?  There is no such thing as disconnection of browser.  Still not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you. I've found out the way to determine :)

Comment: @jfriend00 "a user using many different browsers" means one person opens many kind of browsers such as firefox, chrome, ... Each browser runs with many tabs.
Anyway, the problem has been solved.

Comment: On this site, you do NOT put "Solved" in your title. Instead, you post an answer that explains the answer and then after some period of time, you can accept your own answer by clicking the green checkmark.  That's how you answer your own question.  Not by putting "Solved" in the title.  You will notice that NO other questions here put "Solved" in the title.  The point of this site is questions and answers that provide a lasting reference for the community.  So, you need to either delete your question or provide your solution.

Comment: The best you can do is HTTP session expiry.The statement made above by @SterlingArcher and assumed in the answer by Banners that there is exactly one socket per tab is completely false. The browser maintains a connection pool; may use many more than one connection per tab; any individual connection may outlive a tab it was first used for, be used by a subsequent tab, and so on; and a tab may use any number of connections sequentially as well as in parallel over the course of its life.  Accordingly there is really no such state as 'completely disconnected', and no way to track tab closures.

Answer (score -1):

If all tabs are closed, the user is no longer connected so I assume you want to know on the server if he is completely disconnected?

You should hold a list of sockets against a user identifier (login name or similar) on the server, when a new tab is opened it will have a new socket connection so add it to the list.

When a socket connection is closed, remove it from the socket collection for that user.

When the user's last socket connection is closed, you know that the user has completely disconnected.

**EDIT with example**

something like this (untested and hastily written!)

```
'use strict';

var userConnections = [];

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  var username = socket.request.user.username;

  var existingUser = userConnections.find(function(userConnection){
    return userConnection.username === username;
  })

  if (!existingUser){
    existingUser = { 
      username: username,
      sockets: []
     }
  }

  existingUser.sockets.push(socket);

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {

    var socketIndex = existingUser.indexOf(socket);
    existingUser.sockets.splice(socketIndex, 1);

    if (existingUser.sockets.length === 0){
      //user has completely disconnected
    } 

  });
});
```

**EDIT - after clarification (see comments)**

OP has indicated he wishes to know when all connections for a particular browser instance have disconnected.

Since you cannot access any system information about the browser process from javascript I don't see any way of achieving this.

It is possible to detect the browser type (Chrome/IE/Edge etc) on the client and send this information on socket connection. You could then store your socket information referencing this information. However I don't think this is what the OP wants.

Comment: Thank you. It seems a good solution. 
One more problem: existingUser will lose if I update source code and restart nodejs. How do I keep it? Use Redis???

Comment: @ViệtAnh - If you restart node.js, all socket.io connections will be dropped and then reconnected when the new server instance starts up so this will still work then.  socket.io connections are not persisted across a server restart so you don't want to persist the `existingUser` info either.

Comment: @Banners Like I said, people can use many different browsers. In this case, your code does not work fine. The target are "browsers", not "people".

Comment: sorry I have no idea what you mean. I thought you wanted to know when a user has closed all tabs to your website? You want to know when a user is no longer connected using a chrome browser for instance??

Comment: @Banners Yes. When I open 2 browsers, the existingUser.sockets contains 2 variables. If I close 1 browser, server does not know that the user has been disconnected,  because existingUser.sockets.length = 1 at that time. I need to know when user disconnects from each browser.
Sorry about my bad English

Comment: he hasn't been disconnected - he still has an open socket from the other browser

Comment: perhaps it would help if we knew why you are interested in what browser the user is connected on?

Comment: @Banners Ofcourse he hasn't been disconnected, but the browser has been disconnected. That is the problem. The system we are building is rather large, I can't explain here.

Comment: This answer is completely incorrect. When the last socket has closed the user may still be there with all tabs visible. All that the closures mean is that the HTTP keepalives have expired.

Comment: I agree it doesn't answer the OPs question, however it does tell you when all the sockets for that user have closed which is what I originally thought the question was regarding. I had already added an edit when I realised it was not possible to do what he was asking. Completely incorrect is a little strong.

Comment: 'Complete incorrect' is completely accurate. You are reasoning as follows: 'all tabs closed' => 'user is disconnected', therefore 'user is disconnected' => 'all tabs closed'. It's fallacious.

Comment: All tabs closed => user is disconnected I did state. Nowhere did I state that user is disconnected means all tabs are closed. I already said I misunderstood the question and tried to read between the lines and provide something that it was actually possible to do. ie tell when a user has no socket connections open. Thank you for spending your time reading my posts.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution, it depends on @Banners's one. 
"socket.cookies" stores the browser's cookies
Please let me now if I was missing something.

```
'use strict';

var userConnections = {};

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  var username = socket.request.user.username;
  var visit_id = (socket.cookies.vid) ? socket.cookies.vid : random_unique_id();

  //set cookie here
  setCookie('vid', visit_id, expire);

  if (!userConnections[visit_id])
    userConnections[visit_id] = [];

  userConnections[visit_id].push(socket.id);

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {

    var vid = socket.cookies.vid;

    if (userConnections[vid]) {
        var index = userConnections[vid].indexOf(socket.id);
        if (index != -1)
            userConnections[vid].splice(index, 1);

        if (userConnections[vid].length === 0) {
            delete userConnections[vid];
            //All tabs have been closed
        }
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: It won't work. This will signal users as disconnected who still have browser tabs open. The technique is based on the same fallacy as Banner's and @SterlingArcher's. What you are looking for is HTP session expiry. See my long comment above.